# Too little fps on stream YouTube

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, stream, video-streaming, streaming

In last Friday I bought old computer to stream video and sound on YouTube but I have little FPS on output. 
Input there is a camera(protocol RTSP) 1920x1080 in 15FPS and sound PCM. I want to stream on YouTube on full hd so I don't use libx264 but on copy.

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://user:pass@ip:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0" -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v copy -r 15 -bf 2 -g 30 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -ac 1 -preset ultrafast -bufsize 2M -movflags +faststart -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxxx -threads 2`

My computer:
Intel Core 2 Duo e7500
4GB RAM
Windows 7
Computer use procesor in 1-5%.
Why stream have only 7FPS sometimes 10-13?

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Mulvya - there is http://wklej.org/id/3293484/

Comment: `fps=4.9` & `speed=1.01x` indicates that it's not ffmpeg slowing or dropping frames. Your camera isn't sending 15 fps. Probably due to low light or lack of motion.

Comment: @Stretch Aside from the low light/low fps situation (not a rare occurrence for these cameras) `-tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 15 -bf 2 -g 30` are being ignored due to `-c:v copy`. You don't need `-strict experimental` unless your ffmpeg is old. Option placement matters and trailing options, such as `-threads 2` are generally ignored; it is being ignored anyway due to `-c:v copy`. `-movflags +faststart` isn't needed for a live stream.

Comment: ...and you're outputting FLV and not MOV-type anyway.

Comment: Ok. I removed this option but nothing changed. @Mulvya and @LordNeckbeard this camera lies in church and when testing this it was a night. I tried in this same time(with this same parameters) on second computer on NanoPi A64 and showed 15FPS(night) so problem there is with first computer. Maybe Intel Core 2 Duo don't have software encoders? 
I tried with mp4 and mov and program show me: `muxer does not support non seekable output`

Comment: Please look this:
[information](https://imgur.com/a/TGZxv)